# C++ New Keyword

Tags: c++, heap-memory, new-operator, stack-memory

I was looking at this tutorial about the stack and heap:

[When to use new operator in C++ and when it should not be used?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/when-to-use-new-operator-in-cplusplus-and-when-it-should-not-be-used)

And in the heap example, it uses the `new` keyword, but he began by initializing `int* ptr1` to `NULL`. Is that important, and if so why? Or, is it just wasting space?

I looked at the code and tried thinking why use `NULL` first when you could just use `int* ptr1 = new int(28);`?

Side note:
If someone could also explain the stack and heap in laymans terms, it would be appreciated.

Comment: C++ should be learnt using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of online tutorials. These basic things are explained in any beginner c++ book.

Comment: Most people would think the same. (That's not a good source to learn from. There are no known good online C++ tutorials. Get a good book.)

Comment: There's no good reason.

Comment: There's also the issue that, in C++, one would use`nullptr` and not `NULL`. But there's no need for it here as you and others have pointed out.

Comment: The new operator should hardly be used anymore in current C++. When dynamic memory allocation is needed use [std::make_unique<>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) for polymorphic objects (objects with virtual functions). Or use containers like [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: There are many outdated and bad tutorials around the 'net. Stay away from any one which uses `using namespace std;` or uses `NULL` (instead of the modern `nullptr`).

Comment: The big problem for you is that there is a lot of (outdated) C++ material out there. Most up-to-date information can be found on https://en.cppreference.com/w/, Any current book from this [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Or if you want something more accessible which is still good : https://www.learncpp.com/

Comment: @chi Don't forget those that `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, geeksforgeeks, and ALL of the competitive coding sites

Comment: Stack and heap are in a way just implementation details. C++ works on a higher level, you have variables that live as long as a scope (usually local variables) and variables you can allocate for control over the lifecycle (new/std::make_unique). Stacks and heaps are just one way of managing those requirements.

Comment: @PepijnKramer in no way are they 'just implementation details', the behavior is precisely stated in the c++ specs. A c++ programmer must 100% understand what those behaviors are, along with static data

Comment: Indeed the behaviors are precisely stated and should be understood. The way those behaviors are implemented are / can be hardware specific. And do not require  for example to use a processor stack.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a pointer to `nullptr` on declaration is an excellent practice to adhere to.

But, what they did in the tutorial could be done better. I think it is more of an example of syntax than anything else.

If you can initialize when declaring, that is better and faster. Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`, which is just a macro for `0` and that can be problematic.

If you want to learn more about pointers, learning smart pointers is recommended. They can be a really powerful way to avoid bugs and memory leaks.